# why docker container still can communicate with outside when i shutdown the iptables

Tags: networking, docker

I'm new for docker, and have some basic questions about network of docker container for help, I read the article about network configuration for docker: https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/

there is a part introducing how to use the iptables to make docker container communicate with outside, and actually i can understand this part:

1 from container to outside, there is a masquerade rule on the postrouting chain which is same as SNAT

```
    Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16       !172.17.0.0/16
```

2 from outside to visit the service inside container, there is a DNAT rule in the prerouting chain and then host will forward it to docker0, container will finally receive the packet

```
    Chain DOCKER (2 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:49153 to:172.17.0.2:80
```

But actually, when i stop the iptables service, the docker's networking still works fine, i use the "iptables -L" and "iptables -t nat -L" to check and there is no rule in the kernel, here is my setup (let's assume 10.170.28.0/24 is external net work, and 172.17.0.0/16 is internal network for docker container):

first of all, iptables service is shut down, fiter and nat table is empty as below:

```
    iptables -t nat -L
    Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source 

    iptables -L
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
```

and here is route table in host(host ip is 10.170.28.8):

```
    route
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    10.170.28.0     *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
    192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-data
    link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
    link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
    link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1040   0        0 br-data
    172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
    default         10.170.28.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

it's true that there is rule in the table above to forward packet whose destination is 172.17.0.0/16 to bridge docker0, but before that, who did DNAT to translate 10.170.28.8 to 172.17.0.2(container IP)? and how about traffic from container (172.17.0.0/16) to outside(10.170.28.0/24) work without SNAT or masquerading?

Answer (score 0):

First of all 'stopping' iptables is not possible, it just resets the rules. As your post shows, the policy for the <sup>*filter</sup>INPUT-chain is ALLOW.

Docker runs a TCP forwarding proxy be default, catching all traffic to the forwarded port (verify by `ss -lnp | grep 49153`).

---

A test on my machine showed, that outbound connections are not possible:

1. start the container
2. 'stop' iptables
3. exec into it
4. ping 1.1 ... with no response

When omitting 2., ping works as expected.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.2-ce, build 62479626f2
```

Further details:

- [why is a userspace tcp proxy needed](https://serverfault.com/questions/633604/what-is-the-point-of-the-docker-proxy-process-why-is-a-userspace-tcp-proxy-need)
- [traversal of iptables when connecting to docker client](https://serverfault.com/questions/954391/iptables-traversal-when-connecting-to-docker-client/955175#955175)